# Why is my iptables config not accepting connections from the specified source iP?

Tags: iptables

From machine 192.168.1.2, I have this iptables configuration:

```
$ hostname -I
192.168.1.2
$ iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       192.168.1.3          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:6379
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  943  118K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   20   988 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 5 packets, 300 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 160 packets, 18263 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

When I try to connect to the above machine from 192.168.1.3 over port 6379, it simply hangs until I kill it:

```
$ hostname -I
192.168.1.3
$ nc -z 192.168.1.2 6379
^C
```

What am I doing wrong, that is not allowing me to connect from 192.168.1.3 to 192.168.1.2 over port 6379?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you added the ACCEPT rule shortly after a connection attempt had taken place and been dropped by the policy. If this was the case, a connection tracking entry may have been created for the flow, which included the filtering decision. The connection tracking table acts as a sort of cache for netfilter; it doesn't evaluate all rules for all packets. If there is a matching connection tracking entry, it will consult that.

Always be sure to remove conntrack entries of traffic you're trying to match with new rules, e.g. using the conntrack(8) tool. In your case, you could've done something like

```
conntrack -D -s 192.168.1.3
```

Comment: This seems probable.  Had no idea about this, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I reset iptables, then changed the line in my script that sets this specific iptables rule from this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.3 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
```

to this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6379 -s 192.168.1.3 -j ACCEPT
```

and now it's magically working, even though `iptables -L -n -v` looks identical to what was there before:

```
$ iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 6 packets, 360 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       192.168.1.3          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:6379
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  311  544K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 255 packets, 28839 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Can't say it's not behavior I haven't seen with iptables before though.

edit: for anyone that's curious, I'm actually using `iptables-persistent`, and this is the full file that I've been using:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6379 -s 192.168.1.3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: Did you perhaps have something in your `mangle` or `nat` tables? How did you "reset" iptables? Post the output of `iptables-save` next time rather than `iptables -nvL`

Comment: @fukawi2 I don't think so, I don't have anything that advanced - but I've posted the full script that I've been running (as noted only the first line changed). I used [this script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-flush-all-rules.html) to "reset" iptables.  I'll be sure to do `iptables-save` next time, thanks.  It's probable I messed something up, but iptables still feels pretty finicky in my experience.  Maybe it's just the manner that I'm trying to persist/restore the rules that is causing issues, though.